# How to fetch data from a Microsoft Access database through JDBC and insert the table as a test field in an Applet

Tags: java, sql, ms-access, jdbc, textarea

I have made a small letter game as a Java Applet. I have made a Microsoft Access Database through JBDC for the high scores.

I have managed to insert values (scores) into the database, but I am having trouble fetching them and displaying the table in the `textArea` of an `ajFrame`. I am not even sure if the connection is established. I have created the SQL statement for it.

Comment: In what backend is Access storing its data?
WP:
Microsoft Access is not appropriate for web based applications as its forms and reports only work in Windows ... does not have the features of servers such as SQL Server, Oracle, or other ODBC compliant databases. It also doesn’t have the overhead, hardware, or licensing requirements of server based solutions. People can use Access databases for web based solutions when the number of users is small or if it's just delivering data without editing.

Comment: I don't think it's unreasonable for a small project (I'm assuming the above is such a project!). Note that you can talk to it using JDBC-ODBC, so it'll work irrespective of concerns re. scalability etc.

Comment: If he's using it from a Java applet, he's only using the database engine, Jet/ACE, and not using Access at all.

Answer (score 1):

If you've connected successfully then

```
   connection=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:odbc:databaseName");
```

should return you a connection object and *not* throw a SqlException.

So I would first check that the above is in fact the case.

Note that an applet can *only* talk back to its originating server (this is a security feature). So if your applet is served from server A, and your database is on server B, you should get security exceptions.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your query with sql prompt.
2. verify object name used (Drivermanager,Connection,TextField)
3. Include Exception handling code for sql statements (try and catch )